# How to inject code in posts after X images in Wordpress

Tags: php, html, wordpress

We have a function in Wordpress that show a block of code after 3 paragraphs in posts:

```
add_filter('the_content', 'wpse_ad_content');

function wpse_ad_content($content)
{
    if (!is_single()) return $content;
    $paragraphAfter = 3; //Enter number of paragraphs to display ad after.
    $content = explode("</p>", $content);
    $new_content = '';
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($content); $i++) {
        if ($i == $paragraphAfter) {
            $new_content.= '<div style="col-xs-12">';
            $new_content.= 'code here';
            $new_content.= '</div>';
        }

        $new_content.= $content[$i] . "</p>";
    }

    return $new_content;
}
```

We are trying to complete this function for include and display another block of code only in post that contains at least 8 images (understanding by image each

```
<img src=...
```

).

This block should displayed after the image nº8, if they aren't eight images, the additional function doesn't display nothing.

----- Edit 1:
After trying with the @TimTroiano solution

```
add_filter('the_content', 'wpse_ad_content');

function wpse_ad_content($content)
{
    if (!is_single()) return $content;
    $paragraphAfter = 3; //Enter number of paragraphs to display ad after.
    $imagesAfter = 7; //Enter number of images to display code snippet after.
    $content = explode("</p>", $content);
    $new_content = '';
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($content); $i++) {
        if ($i == $paragraphAfter) {
            $new_content.= '<div class="col-lg-12" style="text-align: center; padding-top: 10px; margin-bottom: 20px;">';
            $new_content.= '<script async src="//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"></script>
         <!-- La nube sobre título -->
         <ins class="adsbygoogle"
            style="display:block"
            data-ad-client=""
            data-ad-slot="7588478595"
            data-ad-format="auto"></ins>
         <script>
            (adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});
         </script>';
            $new_content.= '</div>';
        }

        $new_content.= $content[$i] . "</p>";

        if ($imagesAfter > 0) {
            $imagesAfter -= 1;
        } else {
            $new_content.= '<div class="col-lg-12" style="text-align: center; padding-top: 10px; margin-bottom: 20px;">';
            $new_content.= '<script async src="//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"></script>
<!-- La_Nube_4_Anuncio -->
<ins class="adsbygoogle"
    style="display:block"
    data-ad-client=""
    data-ad-slot="3663644595"
    data-ad-format="auto"></ins>
<script>
(adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});
</script>';
            $new_content.= '</div>';
            $imagesAfter = 7; //Reset number of images to display code after.
        }
    }

    return $new_content;
}
```

We noticed a strange behavior.
1. Consider the paragraphs of text as if they were pictures .
2. In addition repeats the block of code if more images or paragraphs ( multiples of 8) and should appear only once.

Comment: This forum is not for people to write code for you. Please post what you have so people can help you.

Comment: That being said if you already have your PHP displaying the images with a foreach loop or something similar just count a new variable and every time it reaches a certain number insert the code and reset the variable. Ex. 
$i=0; 
foreach ($result as $row) { 
print '<img src="url"'; 
$i++; 
if ($i > 2) { 
**Insert code here**;
$i=0; 
}
}

Comment: Hi @TimTroiano sorry for that. I'll edit the question.

Comment: @TimTroiano I just edited the question. Thank you for your guidelines

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for posting the relevant code. I added a variable $imagesAfter which will count how many images have been inserted before adding your code snippet. When $imagesAfter reaches 0 it inserts whatever you choose to insert and resets $imagesAfter back to the original number.

What I added:

```
$imagesAfter = 7; //Enter number of images to display code snippet after.
if ($imagesAfter > 0) {
    $imagesAfter -= 1;
} else {
    **Code snippet after set number of images goes here**
    $imagesAfter = 7; //Reset number of images to display code after.
}
```

Here is the full code with the part I added in the appropriate places:

```
function wpse_ad_content($content)
{
    if (!is_single()) return $content;
    $paragraphAfter = 3; //Enter number of paragraphs to display ad after.
    $imagesAfter = 7; //Enter number of images to display code snippet after.
    $content = explode("</p>", $content);
    $new_content = '';
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($content); $i++) {
        if ($i == $paragraphAfter) {
            $new_content.= '<div style="col-xs-12">';
            $new_content.= 'code here';
            $new_content.= '</div>';
        }

        $new_content.= $content[$i] . "</p>";

        if ($imagesAfter > 0) {
            $imagesAfter -= 1;
        } else {
            **Code snippet after set number of images goes here**
            $imagesAfter = 7; //Reset number of images to display code after.
        }
    }

    return $new_content;
}
```

Here's an even simpler solution. Use a modulus operator to test if $i is a multiple of 8, then show the image.

```
$if ($i > 0) {
    if ($i % 8 == 0) {
        **Code snippet after set number of images goes here**
    }
}
```

This would go here in your code:

```
function wpse_ad_content($content)
{
    if (!is_single()) return $content;
    $paragraphAfter = 3; //Enter number of paragraphs to display ad after.
    $content = explode("</p>", $content);
    $new_content = '';
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($content); $i++) {
        if ($i == $paragraphAfter) {
            $new_content.= '<div style="col-xs-12">';
            $new_content.= 'code here';
            $new_content.= '</div>';
        }
        $if ($i > 0) {
            if ($i % 8 == 0) {
                **Code snippet after set number of images goes here**
            }
        }

        $new_content.= $content[$i] . "</p>";
    }

    return $new_content;
}
```

Let me know if this solves your problem or if you were looking for something different.

Comment: ¡¡Thank you!! I'll try tomorrow and I'll come back with the answer :)

Comment: Hi @TimTroiano, we tried the 2 options and we received sintax error.

Comment: After solve the sintax error we noticed a strange behavior.
1. Consider the paragraphs of text as if they were pictures .
2. In addition repeats the block of code if more images or paragraphs ( multiples of 8) and should appear only once.

Comment: Can you clarify your problem a little better? If you only want the block of code to appear once you should just use the same method you used with $paragraphAfter. Set another variable and like you did with $paragraph after just test 'if ($i == $imageAfter) { Code snippet here; }'